# How to locate the source of JBAS011470 error in JBoss?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss

I have an application running on JBoss 6.1 EAP that defines 2 persistence units in persistence.xml. I have explicitly named the unit to be used in all injected references to EntityManager, but still the error JBAS011470 happens: Persistence unitName was not specified and there are 2 persistence unit definitions in application deployment deployment "foobar.war".  Either change the application deployment to have only one persistence unit definition or specify the unitName for each reference to a persistence unit.

How can I find out which declaration is causing this problem, since the error message gives no clue?

Comment: pretty frustrating.  i'm wondering the same thing.