# JBoss EAP 6.3 CMT Multiple persistence units

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jboss

This is essentially a duplicate of [How to locate the source of JBAS011470 error in JBoss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220430/how-to-locate-the-source-of-jbas011470-error-in-jboss)

But essentially, As soon as I add a second persistence unit, it gives me this error. It's ridiculous.  I'm not going to disable the JPA subsystem like some people suggest - that sounds wrong.

My persistence.xml setup is as follows, where `java:/NAME` is set up as a datasource in standalone.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation=
         "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">


<persistence-unit name="name" transaction-type="JTA">

    <jta-data-source>java:/NAME</jta-data-source>

    <class>za.co.classes.A</class>
    <class>za.co.classes.B</class>
    <class>za.co.classes.C</class>


    <properties>

        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
              value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
              value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name"
            value="java:jboss/persistence/NAME" />
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name"
            value="java:jboss/persistence/em/NAME" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="za.co.equrahealth.dao.SQLServerDialect" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

The error starts as soon as I add a second persistence unit.  So spring context is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I luckily have multiple databases within the same schema, so I came up with a workaround.  But it's obviously not going to solve the problem when there are multiple schemas.  I think the cause of this issue might actually be a bug in JBoss.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

private EntityManager getEntityManager(String source)
{

    if ("a".equalsIgnoreCase(source))
    {
        entityManager.createNativeQuery("USE A_DB;").executeUpdate();
    }
    else 
    {
        entityManager.createNativeQuery("USE B_DB").executeUpdate();
    }

    return entityManager;
}
```